# Passing an array list of string to function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, web-scraping

I'm a beginner in Python and I'm trying to write a function.

For symbol, I have a list that I'm fetching from the database

```
cur.execute("SELECT sym FROM data")

list = cur.fetchall()              ####fetches list from database column

 

[['AAPL']                       ####This is the output of list
 ['MSFT']
 ['GOOGL']
 ['TSLA']
 ['AMZN']
 ['FB']
 ['V']
 ['BABA']
 ['WMT']]
```

How do I pass the values of this list in **symbol** for the below function?

```
    symbol = 
    url_cf = 'https://somewebsite.com' + symbol

    def scrape_data():
        def dir_create():
            # base dir
            _dir = "/Users/Desktop/Companies"
    
            # create dynamic name
            _dir2 = os.path.join(_dir, symbol)
    
            # create 'dynamic' dir, if it does not exist
            if not os.path.exists(_dir2):
                os.makedirs(_dir2)
    
    
        dir_create()
    
    
        # Scraping Cash Flow
        def cash_flow():
        .
        .
        page = requests.get(url_cf, headers)
        .
        .
        #### Some function for scraping
        .
        .
        path = '/Users/Desktop/Companies' + '/' + symbol
        sheet_name = str('cash_flow_' + symbol + '.xlsx')
        .
        .
        cash_flow()

scrape_data()
```

I wish to perform scrape_data() for each symbol in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can just simply pass the list to the function like this:

```
def scrape_data(symbol):
    #...

scrape_data(symbol)
```

In this case, its important to say, `symbol` is a list, and you must loop through them inside you function.
But, if you would like to run the function for each value in `symbol`, you should do:

```
def scrape_data(symbol):
    #...

for symb in symbol:
    scrape_data(symb)
```

In this case, the function will get elements from the list `symbol` one-by-one.

Also, please rename you list. You use the same name for a list outside of the function, and for a string inside your function.

Answer (score 0):

Use a parameter and a loop:

```
def scrape_data(symbol):
    url_cf = f'https://somewebsite.com/{symbol}'
    ....


for sym, in list:
    scrape_data(sym)
```

In Python3 you can use f-strings to make variable concatenation easier
Note the `,` after `sym` in the `for` loop declaration. This will unpack the list elements within the list. This will fail if there are multiple values per row, which shouldn't happen given your db query